# What do I need to learn as prerequisites for logic programming in miniKanren or Prolog?

Tags: reference-request, logic

I'm interested in logic programming for AI.
Can I just learn logic programming without any math knowledge?
If I couldn't, what do I need to learn?

Comment: You can, all required theory can be learned by-the-way, but I would say that having some background in the following math areas is really helpful: all kinds of logic, set theory, groups theory, graph theory. Other areas might be useful, depending on your particular task, plus all math which can be somehow related to AI construction, which is, essentially, all math, if not to be too pedantic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prolog is generally used for defining and solving logical formulas as the language is rooted in first-order logic. As *noncom* mentions, one must understand first-order logic, specifically resolution and inference (ie backward chaining).

Pathfinding and graph traversals are common in the study of Artificial Intelligence and hence, one should have a solid grasp on graph theory and some knowledge of commonly used search algorithms {BFS, DFS, Iterative Deepening DFS, A*, etc} [1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/artificial_intelligence/artificial_intelligence_popular_search_algorithms.htm).

Ivan Bratko's **Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence** is a good place to begin reading [2](http://catalogue.pearsoned.ca/educator/product/Prolog-Programming-for-Artificial-Intelligence/9780321417466.page). It is divided into two distinct sections; the first outlining the syntax and structure of the Prolog language and the second section outlining specific concepts related to the study of AI. The majority of the necessary mathematical background is discussed throughout the book.